# MYSQL PHP jump through many tables by one query

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

Is it possible to get data from one table when necessary data is in the other one(and so on a few times)? I mean, I have to get result, fetch array, pull all the data in php, make another query... and repeat it a several times before I get the wanted result. Could it be done in one query or have you guys got any ideas about optimization for such issue? I've been searching, but I really didn't find anything what makes sense for me.

UPDATE:
Thanks! JOIN fixed my problems but I got some more to work on. Let's say I've got tables like this
Users:

```
ID  Name
1   Adam
2   John
3   Lana



Roles(with users ids)
ID  Name         Cleaner   Soldier   Doctor 
1   Ship crew    2         1         3
```

How can I get my result like:
[1,Ship crew,John,Adam,Lana] in php without making many queries? I mean I'd like to load records from another table for a several fields depending on primary key ID.

EDIT:
OK I got it, I just needed some practice with mysql. It's not so hard as I thought it could be. Thanks for that join now I know what I was looking for :)

Comment: Yes, it is called `join`ing.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could show a real example here - with table structures and a description of what you want to query.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible yes, you can use the "JOIN" technique to collate the tables or you can use the "IN" clause in your query .

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `IN` clause.